# Boot uboot linux kernel on a VM

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, qemu

I have a compiled kernel and uboot images like so:

```
u-boot.bin uImage
```

I compiled them using the `arm-none-gnueabi` and `fsl-linaro toolchain`.

How can I boot them as in a virtual machine?

**EDIT:**
The image usually runs on a device with a `freescale i.MX6 solo` processor

Comment: As long as you don't have arm hardware, you need to install an emulator (QEMU), and pass the images in the commandline parameters

Comment: @gerhardd. How do I pass both? With which arguments? I tried reading about QEMU but I didn't find where to put both of them

Comment: try 'qemu-arm-XXX --help`

Comment: @gerhardd.I did try that. There seems to be no way to fit these files as input and for QEMU to just boot from one of them (and I can't find how to do both, they are probably needed for each other). I also tried QTEMU but it requires .img files which I don't have

Comment: @ gerrhard I have an image that usually runs on `freescale i.MX6 solo`for that matter